# Positioning the starting position of Horizontal Scrollbar slider on the right

Tags: c#, javascript, scrollbar

I want to Set the Horizontal Scrollbar slider to the right without using css direction:"ltr" or dir="ltr" or an asp:Panel direction="rightToLeft"....

i just want to access the object that controls the Horizontal scrollbar slider to give it the position.
from aspx page or the aspx.cs.

aspx page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/BeginScrollFromRight.js"></script> . . .
<body id="body" style="overflow:auto; height:100%;width:100%;"> . . . </body>
```

js page :

```
function BeginScrollFromRight() 
{
  $("#body").scrollLeft($(window).width());
}
```

I need to have the same effect for the direction:rtl but only for the horizontal scrollbar because other object are not supported when using direction:rtl

```
<td id="tdView" runat="server" dir="ltr" align="center">
                        <table onclick="hideMenusComplex();" oncontextmenu="hideMenusComplex();" id="tblView" runat="server">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblView" runat="server" ForeColor="#5E82D6" Visible="false"><%= translate("View : ") %></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    &nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <cc1:Combobox  AlignContainer="Center" ID="ddlViews" runat="server"  OnClientChange="onChangeValue()"
                                        FolderStyle="../EsStyles/ComboXpBlue" AutoPostbackEnable="false" Width ="200">
                                    </cc1:Combobox>
                                </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblViewArabic" runat="server" ForeColor="#5E82D6" Visible="false"><%= translate("View : ") %></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
```

This is the code and the ddlViews is the dropdown list that is opening in a wrong way, the dropdown list is not opening under the control is opening on the left of the control.

Comment: I have never seen a scrollbar that wasn't already on the right side. What's your use case here?

Comment: I need to position the horizontal scrollbar to start on the right because we have arabic language support.

Comment: `the dropdown list is not opening under the control is opening on the left of the control.` Do you mean that the `<select>` part of the combobox is to the left of the `<input>` part of the combo box? Rather than beneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For languages the read right-to-left, `direction: rtl` is really the only way that will work well, in the end.

If you just want to scroll all the way to the right, *[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)* JavaScript like:

```
$("#YourContentDiv").scrollLeft($("#YourContentDiv").width());
```

or:

```
$(window).scrollLeft($(window).width());
```

will do it.

.
In case you are new to [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can add it to your page, like this.:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function jQueryMain ()
    {
        $("#YourContentDiv").scrollLeft($("#YourContentDiv").width());

        $(window).scrollLeft($(window).width());
    }


    $(document).ready (jQueryMain);
</script>
```

.
PS:  jQuery takes most of the cross-browser hassle out of JavaScript like this.

Comment: when i am using $(window) in a javascript file i'm getting an error :  object expected. maybe there's no way to fix this problem

Comment: @Codeffect: Do you have jQuery in your page?  See the updated answer for the full solution.

Comment: The horizontal scrollbar slider didn't begin from right to left. still the same problem

Comment: @Codeffect:  What do you mean, "didn't begin from right to left"?  It was just supposed to scroll over, other than that it would be the same because `direction: rtl` was used.  Please post your page code and, ideally a sketch of what you want.

Comment: @Codeffect: could you paste the code into your question?  And be sure to indent it all 4 spaces so that we can make it out.  Or you can use http://pastebin.com/ .
If the only reason you are not using `rtl` is because some objects do not suport it, the smart thing would be to use `rtl` and then use jQuery to "fix" just those objects.

Comment: PS:  Did you try this style?  `head, body {direction: rtl;}`?  That is, style both the head and the body, at minimum.

Comment: when i try to put the body {direction: rtl;} it works fine but there's only one problem :a dropdown control is not opening well .
it just opens well if the  body {direction: ltr;}

Comment: Thank you for your help but its really a predicament situation...
and i prefer to find a solution without changing the properties of the dropdown.

Comment: how to fix the dropdown with the jquery ?

Comment: @Codeffect: `"how to fix the dropdown with the jquery"` You have to post code that shows the problem and describe what the actual problem is.  When I test an `rtl` page, drop-downs (`<select>` s) work as I expect them to.  But of course, I am not directly familiar with any rtl languages.

Comment: i added the drop down list code. now is there a way to move the list under the control with JQuery ?

Comment: First, how are you calling `BeginScrollFromRight()`?  Are you using ` $(document).ready ()`?  You should.
Re: `"is there a way to move the list under the control with JQuery?"` Probably.  Unfortunately, I no longer develop with Microsoft tools, so I don't know the **generated HTML** for that Combobox control.  Can you post the generated html, for this control as it appears on the output page?

Comment: BeginScrollFromRight() is located in a js file .
and the aspx page is calling this function on client page load,
but i didnt work so i removed it.